# extjs Possibility of using grid widgets in custom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

Is it possible to use these widgets http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#widget-grid in costum elements div/span, not in a panel?

I know only about Progressbar:

```
Ext.create("Ext.ProgressBar", {
                        renderTo: costumSpan[0],
                        value: .5
                    });
```

What about others?

Comment: can't you use `renderTo` property in your grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved me.
For example:

```
                   Ext.create("Ext.widget", {
                        xtype: "sparklinebox",
                        // xtype: "sparklineline"
                        // xtype: "sparklinepie "
                        // xtype: "sparklinediscrete"
                        // xtype: "sparklinebar"
                        // xtype: "sparklinebullet"
                        // xtype: "sparklinebox"
                        // xtype: "sparklinetristate"
                        renderTo: 'dom-element-id'
                        height: 20,
                        width: 10,
                        values: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

- Ext.button.Button
- Ext.ProgressBar
- Ext.form.field.ComboBox
- Ext.slider.Single
- everything from the chart package

Answer (score 0):

If you open `Details` panel (folded on the right side on [Kitchen sink example](http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#widget-grid) page you posted) you should see how that grid widget in example is created.

There is `extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'` line inside `KitchenSink.view.grid.WidgetGrid` definition that tells you that `KitchenSink.view.grid.WidgetGrid` inherits all `Ext.grid.Panel` properties and behaviors (and extends that with some of its own). This practically means that `KitchenSink.view.grid.WidgetGrid` supports [Ext.grid.Panel.renderTo](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-renderTo) configuration, so it should be perfectly valid if you construct `KitchenSink.view.grid.WidgetGrid` like this:

```
Ext.create("KitchenSink.view.grid.WidgetGrid", {
    renderTo: costumSpan[0]
    // ... Other configuration options
});
```

I guess you are just beginning with ExtJs framework, maybe you should take a look at [ExtJs class system](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/classes.html) and [Components](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/components.html) articles. Lots of other help material for ExtJs concepts can be found [on ExtJs documentation page](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/).